# Link wordpress with a SQl + MongoDB + .NET

Tags: database, sql

This may sound a bit crazy,

I have a website using different DB, One SQl; one MongoDB, and a .net API

I would really really love to be able to move this to a wordpress installation ( or Magento).

Do you know if there is anyway to connect a wordpress website with mongodb + .net - and sql.

some part of the website is using one of those DB. But I would need to have the wordpress dashboard for each of this.

I know it can sounds totally insame .. . but it would be a big help to have your opinion in this :)

Thank you guys :)

Comment: I prefer to stick with MySQL DB, because it gives best performance for WordPress, just convert you db to MySQL WP compatible

Comment: it is possible if you can find the php libraries that will can provide the facilities to connect to those DBs.

Comment: Hm - For big website - Mysql can ge quite slow comapre to MongoDB, and I have a lot of different kind of data on this mongo - so I need to keep mongodb - but make it connect to wordpress for some part....

IN term of php library - DO you have any examples ? Is it a big big deal to do ?? Thank you for your time guys :)